# How To Get Data (File Name) From Mysql when Today Not Inserted Record

Tags: php

I use a cronjob to insert data every day. How to notify if today there is no data insert. The notification is file name where Not insert process today.

this is the script if there is an insert data today and this script work, How if noting inserted today:

```php
$getFileSycn = $db->SELECT('FILE_NAME,LAST_UPDATED')
                   ->FROM('T_DATA_SYNCHRONIZE')
                   ->WHERE('DATE(LAST_UPDATED) = CURDATE()')
                   ->QUERY()->FETCHALL();

$fileName = array();
foreach($getFileSycn as $row) {
    $fileName[]      = $row['FILE_NAME'];
    if(substr($row['FILE_NAME'],0,2) == 'WP') {
        echo 'WP_PLU03.CSV Is inserted';
    } elseif(substr($row['FILE_NAME'],0,3) == 'CRM') {
        echo 'CRM_MASMC_20210407.csv Is Inserted';
    } elseif(substr($row['FILE_NAME'],0,6) == 'MEMBER') {
        echo 'MEMBER_20210250.csv Is inserted';
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(count($getFileSycn) > 0)` then do the foreach code